# What is wrong with my question?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I am trying to write this question on arqade but i am repeatedly getting the error- This question does not meet our quality standards.

The question is:-

Today while playing clash royale, i opened a golden chest but i got disconnected. When i again opened the game, my golden chest was not there.

Did i get the cards that were in the chest?

If i did not get the cards, is there any way i can get that chest back?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards

Comment: I tried doing all that but it doesn't work

Comment: What was your title? Did you try changing all the  "i" to "I"?

Comment: The title was Did I get these cards?

Comment: "proper spelling, grammar, capitalization, and punctuation" would me my guess *Edit: just saw your answer* :)

Answer (score 3):

Ok, thanks to Wipqozn, I got the answer to my question. Solution of the problem was that i had to just change all the 'i's to 'I's. Thanks Wipqozn :)

Comment: For future reference: we place a fairly high premium on high quality content here, and that goes all the way down to little stuff like spelling, grammar, punctuation, etc. taking the extra ten seconds to pay attention to those things and proofread your posts will pay dividends.